# Убрать тень от диаграммы в Q3DSurface

Tags: c++

Подскажите, как можно убрать тень от объектов в Q3DSurface?

Answer (score 1):

surface->setShadowQuality( QAbstract3DGraph::ShadowQuality::ShadowQualityNone );